# How do you use a for loop to call all functions inside all methods inside an object?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, methods, setinterval

I have a timer called 'updater' that runs every second. I also have an object 'particleFunctions' that contains several functions in its methods. I want all 'update' functions in 'particleFunctions' to execute ever second.

Ideally I want the console.log to output output this message every second:

```
0
1
2
```

```js
var updater = setInterval(createParticles, 1000);

var particleFunctions = {
    particle0 : function(i){
        this.update = function(i){
            console.log(i);
        }
    },
    particle1 : function(i){
        this.update = function(i){
            console.log(i);
        }
    },
    particle2 : function(i){
        this.update = function(i){
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}

function createParticles(){
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(particleFunctions).length; i++){
        particleFunctions['particle' + i].update(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try change your json to "particle1" (using quotes) instead of particle1.

Comment: Your `particleX` functions all do the same thing: set `this.update` to a function that does `console.log(i)`, but your code doesn't ever call the `particleX()` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you want the `i` to be called, but something like this would do the trick:

```js
var particleFunctions = {
        particle0 : function(i){
            this.update = function(){
                console.log(i);
            }
            return this;
        },
        particle1 : function(i){
            this.update = function(){
                console.log(i);
            }
            return this;
        },
        particle2 : function(i){
            this.update = function(){
                console.log(i);
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
    
    function createParticles(){
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(particleFunctions).length - 1; i++){
            particleFunctions['particle' + i](i).update();
        }
    }
    
    var updater = setInterval(createParticles, 1000);
```

The main problem is that `particleFunctions['particle' + i]` returns a function, so you have to call it to be able to call `update` in sequence.

Also, your `Object.keys(particleFunctions).length` was giving an index out of bounds so I added the `- 1` for the check